# Why finite automatons are defined with help of tuple? Like DFA can be defined by 5 tuple but why we can not do the same with Set?

Tags: set, computer-science, discrete-mathematics

Why finite automatons are defined with help of tuple? Like DFA can be defined by 5 tuple but why  we can not do the same  with Set ? Is there any odering present among the tuples?

Comment: I don't get your question. The 5-tuple in this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) describes a specific DFA. What do you mean by ordering among the tuples? Also, Set is a much more basic structure.

Comment: As per the basic definition of tuple it is a ordered list objects , my question is why we need tuple for FA definition. i.e is there any ordering among Q,sigma,Delta,q0,F.

Comment: Don't get mislead by the "ordered" in "ordered list of objects". Here it means only that you have five objects each with a definite role in the definition. There is no order relation between the objects except this.

Answer (score 1):

A DFA is formally defined by five things:

1. its input alphabet E
2. its states Q
3. its start state q0
4. its accepting states A
5. its transitions f

Suppose you're given four finite non-empty sets and some element (which might itself be a finite non-empty set). They are in no particular order. Which one is the alphabet, which is the set of states, which is the start state, which are the accepting states, which are the transitions?

It might be possible to determine this logically by working out which are logically possible and which are not. However, it's much easier just to put the burden on the person giving you the five things to say which they are, which is basically the same as requiring that they be given to you in a particular order.

Mathematical objects are not inherently of some specific type in the way that objects are instances of a class. In a sense, all of these objects are reducible to sets of sets and so they are not readily distinguishable, per se, except insofar as they may or may not contain distinct elements.